# i2cdetect show bus is different every time

Tags: gpio, i2c

[image: different buses][image: circuit diagram]I am use ToF sensor(VL53L0X) on my Raspberry Pi's GPIO,I discover one problem about VL53L0X.

I am input command

```
i2cdetect -l
```

It's show

> i2c-1 i2c         bcm2835 I2C adapter                 I2C adapter

Then I input

```
i2cdetect -y 1
```

It's show :

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- 09 0a -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 18 -- -- -- -- -- -- 1f
20: -- -- 22 23 -- 25 26 -- -- 29 -- -- -- 2d -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- 42 43 44 -- -- -- -- -- -- 4b -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

input same command again:

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 0f
10: 10 11 12 13 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 29 -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 38 -- -- -- -- -- 3e 3f
40: -- 41 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

i2cdetect is showing different buses every time.

I am checked my circuit diagram, it's fine.
Maybe sensor trouble?

Thx everyone.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
If I disconnect SDA from sensor
[image]

When Raspberry pi's SDA connect GND, terminal show me this:
 [image]
I think it is normal, there is a read to the sensor.

Comment: Your wiring is wrong.  If you edit your question and add a clear photo showing the connections we might be able to help.

Comment: thx a lot , bro! I was had upload pic about this question.

Comment: As far as I can tell the wiring looks okay.  What does i2cdetect show if you disconnect SDA?

Comment: I am update my question behind '///////', THX bro.

Comment: Those results look correct.  Have you another I2C device to connect in place of the current device?

Comment: Nope. I change the sensor. It's working!